# Set startup script in WinPE to show in which mode the PC has booted

Tags: script, cmd.exe, winpe

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to make a WinPE iso and test if it has booted up on BIOS or UEFI mode. Currently I can test this with the following command:

```vb
reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEFirmwareType
```

This command returns `0x1` if the PC is booted into BIOS mode, or `0x2` if the PC is booted in UEFI mode.

[Technet shows a script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn293283.aspx) to show this automatically after WinPE has booted by adding this to startnet.cmd:

```vb
wpeutil UpdateBootInfo
for /f "tokens=2* delims=  " %%A in ('reg query HKLM\System \CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEFirmwareType') DO SET Firmware=%%B
:: Note: delims is a TAB followed by a space.
if %Firmware%==0x1 echo The PC is booted in BIOS mode.
if %Firmware%==0x2 echo The PC is booted in UEFI mode.
```

But when I boot up the WinPE, the cmd shows this error:

```vb
X:windows\system32>wpeinit UpdateBootInfo

X:\windows\system32>for /F "tokens=2* delims= " %A in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEFirmwareType') DO SET Firmware=%B 
echo was unexpected at this time.
X:\windows\system32>if ==0x1 echo The PC is booted in BIOS mode.
X:\windows\system32>_
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it is related to how the ifs are being evaluated: if %Firmware%==0x1, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your `for` command is failing so `Firmware` is not being set.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the script by replacing the whitespace in your delims variable and putting an actual tab and space in its place.

```
wpeutil UpdateBootInfo
for /f "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEFirmwareType') DO SET Firmware=%%B

if %Firmware%==0x1 echo The PC is booted in BIOS mode.
if %Firmware%==0x2 echo The PC is booted in UEFI mode.
```

**NOTE: ** I edited the script in notepad.exe to ensure proper encoding.  A copy/paste of the above code may not work.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue because I was literally copying/pasting the text.  Unfortunately there are (2) spaces after "delims" in the Technet example.  Change the first space to be a tab and this should correct it.  There's even the note mentioning it; it's been a long day.  Be sure NOT to include the greater/less than signs below "<" and ">".

for /f "tokens=2* delims=" %%A....